# How can I bind an array with asp-for tag?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I would like to ask, how can I bind an array in Asp.NET Core MVC ?

```
<input type="text" asp-for="Requests[@index].Name" />
```

It was working very well in older versions of ASP MVC.
This example shows "Internal server error".

"*An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to process this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.*"

ViewModel class example:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public List<Model> Requests {get;set;}
}
```

Model class example:

```
public class Model
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

How it should work ? After you submit a form with these inputs, MVC should automaticly create and map the list in ModelView. That's how It works in ASP.NET MVC 4.

Comment: Can you explain further what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I added more description.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You need to use a valid expression with `asp-for` that can be compiled, basically if `index` is a variable you are using in a for loop then you would write `<input asp-for="@Model.Requests[index].Name" />`

Full example (I've used `i` as the loop variable instead of `index`):

```
@model MyProject.TodoItemList

<ul>
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Requests.Count; i++)
{
    <li>                
        <label asp-for="@Model.Requests[i].Name"></label>
        <input asp-for="@Model.Requests[i].Name"/>
        @* Or the old html helpers if you prefer
           @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Requests[i].Name)
        *@                
    </li>
}
</ul>
```

For more info, check *Expression names and Collections* in [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/working-with-forms#the-input-tag-helper)

Comment: Thanks! This one works! I was using foreach and it didn't work.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to bind the list using a **separate partial view**:

First, create your action that returns the list.

```
public async Task<ActionResult> UpdateTable([FromForm]Filter filter)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {           
        List<Model> model = new List<Model>();
        ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix = string.Format("Requests");
        return PartialView("_PartialViewOfModel", model);
    }
    return BadRequest(ModelState);
}
```

And this code will go in your partial view.

```
@model List<Model>
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
{
    <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" asp-for="@Model[i].Name" />
}
```