# Forms inside foreach loop in Razor Page

Tags: razor, asp.net-core

I have a standard Razor Page that lists all Orders in my database. It's coded pretty standard: `IList<Order>` bind property in page model, **OnPost** method. However, each of the records in a table has a column with a **select** element that shows the current status of the order, and a **button** to save  the new status if the user decides to change it. Sort of an inline edit of the status for each row.

[image: Form Preview]

So I have a **foreach** loop in my page that cycles through all my orders:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Orders)
{
   <tr><td>...</td></tr>
   <tr>
      <td>
         <form method="post" class="form-inline">
            <input type="hidden" value="@item.Id"/>
            <select asp-for="@item.OrderStatusId"
                    class="form-control form-control-sm"
                    asp-items="ViewBag.OrderStatusId"></select>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm">
               <i class="fas fa-save"></i>
            </button>
         </form>
      </td>
   </tr>
}
```

As you can see, the last column is a **form**. What I want done is to be able to submit to my **OnPost** method, the order id (hidden **input** element in the form) and the selected state (**select** in element the form). However, these parameters always show up as null in the method. I'm guessing it has something to do with the fact that, because there are multiple **asp-for** elements for the same property name (one for each form - each order/row), Razor gets confused and doesn't know which one to send.

Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `foreach` loop in your example generates same `name` attribute for `<select>` elements, which explains why Razor got confused (and it's also invalid HTML). Assumed that `Model.Orders` implements `IEnumerable`, you should use a `for` loop and numeric index for every iteration to generate different `<select>` element names:

```
<form method="post" class="form-inline">
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Orders.Count; i++)
{
   <tr><td>...</td></tr>
   <tr>
      <td>
            <input type="hidden" value="@item.Id"/>
            <select asp-for="Model.Orders[i].OrderStatusId" class="form-control form-control-sm"
                    asp-items="ViewBag.OrderStatusId"></select>
      </td>
   </tr>
}
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm">
      <i class="fas fa-save">Save</i>
   </button>
</form>
```

**Note:** I intentionally put the `<form>` & submit `<button>` tags outside the loop because it's unnecessary to create multiple `<form>` tags (and multiple submit buttons) without setting `action` attribute inside `for` loop, unless specified otherwise.

Similar issue: [How can I bind an array with asp-for tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41873171/how-can-i-bind-an-array-with-asp-for-tag)

Comment: Thanks for the information, I'll give it a shot, although I do need the form and button inside the loop, so they can save them individually. I do have a question, however: what do the parameters in the OnPost method have to be named like? id and orderStatusId?

Comment: The parameter names should be same as names passed in form elements. In case of multiple `select` elements passed by form submit, you should set parameter type as `List<T>` with `T` depends on selected value type.

Answer (score 1):

The select tag helper will automatically generate a multi-select if the property specified in the asp-for attribute is an IEnumerable.

```
public class OrderModel
{
     public IEnumerable<string> OrderStatusId{ get; set; }
}
```

Binding the asp-for attribute to the OrderStatusId property as follows:

```
<select asp-for="OrderStatusId" 
    asp-items="ViewBag.OrderStatus">
</select>
```