# <select> options from database in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a database where "Categories" table is located. When I create news in admin panel I have to choose a category. How can I implement it?

EditGuides.cs

```
@model Guide
<form asp-controller="Panel" asp-action="EditGuides" method="post">
        <input asp-for="Id" type="hidden" />
        <div>
            <label>Title</label>
            <input asp-for="Title" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <label>Category</label>
            <select asp-for="???" ???></select>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Models/Category.cs

```
namespace Project.Models
{
    public class Category
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; } = "";
    }
}
```

Comment: What has this to do with C?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52157469/forms-inside-foreach-loop-in-razor-page

Answer (score 0):

asp-for is for the value of the  you need.
The asp-items is for your Category List Item(get the category from the database).

```
@model Guide
@inject Project.Models.Category Category
<form asp-controller="Panel" asp-action="EditGuides" method="post">
        <input asp-for="Id" type="hidden" />
        <div>
            <label>Title</label>
            <input asp-for="Title" />
        </div>`enter code here`
        <div>
            <label>Category</label>
            <select asp-for="@Category.Id" asp-items="CatagoryList"></select>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```